# RVM 1.9.2 install fails on Cloud9 IDE — bash syntax error

Tags: ruby, rvm, cloud9-ide

I'm trying a classic Ruby install via RVM un Cloud9, but I get a bash error:

```
bash: 1.1G: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".1G")
```

[image: Screenshot of the error]

UPDATE:

So I did some digging into the RVM script which does the magic, and it seems this error comes from this part of the script `/usr/local/rvm/scripts/functions/utility` (line 416):

```
__rvm_calculate_space_free()
{
  # OpenBSD does not have 'df -m' param
  __free_space="$( \command \df -Pk "$1" | __rvm_awk 'BEGIN{x=4} /Free/{x=3} $3=="Avail"    {x=3} END{print $x}' )"
  if [[ "${__free_space}" == *M ]]
  then __free_space="${__free_space%M}" # some systems ignore -k and print M
  else __free_space="$(( __free_space / 1024 ))"
  fi
}
```

This is *way* beyond my knowledge, but it would seem to me that the reported free space includes that `G` which somehow messes with the operation, hence the arithmetic error.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Cloud9 uses is onw version of df that is not compatibible with RVM options `-Pk`. The team is working on a fix. In the meantime there is a fix in RVM to solve the issue: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2958#event-159335592

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to modify your PATH variable like from:

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.30/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/mnt/shared/bin:/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/.bin:/home/ubuntu/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/mnt/shared/sbin:/opt/gitl:/opt/go/bin:/mnt/shared/c9/app.nw/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin
```

to

```
$ export PATH=/home/ubuntu/.nvm/v0.10.30/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/.bin:/home/ubuntu/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/mnt/shared/sbin:/opt/gitl:/opt/go/bin:/mnt/shared/c9/app.nw/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/mnt/shared/bin
```

Note the `/mnt/shared/bin` dir is now at the last position of the PATH variable.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try installing it as root (so with 'sudo rvm install 1.9.2')?

Comment: rvm generally doesn't need to be installed as root. In fact, to be able to work with sudo at all, you need to do some tricks (i.e. to use `rvmsudo`. Still, you should never have to install stuff with rvm using sudo.

Comment: I also tried sudo, but it's the same issue. Like @HolgerJust said, you shouldn't need to do it anyway. I did some more digging and will update the issue.